# Log file is being created with root user

Tags: laravel

I have setted a cron using schedule funcion in `kernel.php` file of laravel. It is calling a method which is writing logs.

My problem is log file is created with root user. Can I set the permissions of the file or execute that cron with a certain user?

Comment: What user is running your cron?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the file permission with the user you want with this command:

```
cd path-to-log-folder && chown your-user:your-group file-name
```

Otherwise, you can set the cronjob run by a specific user with this command:

```
crontab -u your-user -e
```

and change the ownership of your log file with the same user (I prefer this way).